# Real-time search filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a user directory made out of rows and column and I would like to have a real-time search filter.

It works but unfortunately it hides more than I would like. I am not very good when it comes to javascript or jQuery.

```
 <a href="" class="mdi mdi-account-search" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".search-input" style="font-size:400%"></a>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="container collapse search-input">
                <input class="col-lg-3"  id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
            </div>
        </div>
        @foreach( array_chunk($instructors, 3) as $threeInstructors)
        <div class="row">
            @foreach ($threeInstructors as $instructor)
            <div class="col-lg-4" id="myDIV">
                <div class="card m-b-20">
                    <div class="card-body">

                        <div class="media">
                            <img class="d-flex mr-3 rounded-circle thumb-lg" src="assets/images/users/avatar-2.jpg" alt="Generic placeholder image">
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <h5 id="namesearch" class="m-t-10 font-18 mb-1">{{$instructor->getName()}}</h5>
                                <p id="emailsearch" class="text-muted m-b-5">{{$instructor->getEmail()}}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row text-center m-t-20">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                <h5 class="mb-0">{{$instructor->getTotalCourses()}}</h5>
                                <p class="text-muted font-14">Courses</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <ul class="social-links text-center list-inline mb-0 mt-3">
                             <li class="list-inline-item">
                                <a title="" href="{{ route('admin.userAdjustments', array($instructor->getAuthIdentifier())) }}"  data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" class="tooltips" data-original-title="User Settings" style="text-decoration: none;"><i class="mdi mdi-account-settings-variant" style="font-size:170%"></i></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                <a href="" title="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" class="tooltips" data-original-title="Edit Info"><i class="mdi mdi-account-card-details" data-id="{{ $instructor->getAuthIdentifier() }}" data-name="{{ $instructor->getName() }}" data-email="{{ $instructor->getEmail() }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".editInfo" style="font-size:170%"></i></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                <a href="" title="" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" class="tooltips" data-original-title="Delete"><i class="mdi mdi-account-remove" data-id="{{ $instructor->getAuthIdentifier() }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".deleteModal" style="font-size:170%"></i></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- end col -->
            @endforeach
        </div> <!-- end row -->
        @endforeach
```

[image]
and when you search for something it removes too much of the html. I want the div square to be kept with all of its elements while only displaying the one with the right info
[image]

this is the javascript code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myDIV *").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this search filter jquery

```js
$('[data-search]').on('keyup', function() {
 var searchVal = $(this).val();
 var filterItems = $('[data-filter-item]');

 if ( searchVal != '' ) {
  filterItems.addClass('hidden');
  $('[data-filter-item][data-filter-name*="' + searchVal.toLowerCase() + '"]').removeClass('hidden');
 } else {
  filterItems.removeClass('hidden');
 }
});
```

```css
.container {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 width: 50%;
}

.search {
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.items {
 
}

[data-filter-item] {
 padding: 15px;
 background-color: #ccc;
 border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.hidden {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="search">
  <input type="text" placeholder="search" data-search />
 </div>
 <div class="items">
  <div data-filter-item data-filter-name="apple">Apple</div>
  <div data-filter-item data-filter-name="google">Google</div>
  <div data-filter-item data-filter-name="microsoft">Microsoft</div>
  <div data-filter-item data-filter-name="hp">HP</div>
  <div data-filter-item data-filter-name="dell">Dell</div>
  <div data-filter-item data-filter-name="samsung">Samsung</div>
 </div>
</div>
```